# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Angular SSR alongside multipage controllers and views

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

I've initialised the .NET Core Web Project with Angular and tried to add another controller with a view. They are just the basic controller and views.

### MedicalController.cs

```
public class MedicalController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### Dashboard.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
}

<h2>Dashboard</h2>
```

I want to migrate an old .NET Framework 4.6 project to .NET Core. Changing the .NET side if things isn't a problem. It's the existing functionality (controllers, views, scripts) I want to run alongside the SPA.

I thought it would just be a case of changing the client-side routing like so:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    //{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    //{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

I've also tried using a separate _Layout page for the SPA.

How could I get the SPA to only kick in when the route starts with "/app/".

Here is the stacktrace:

```
NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'medical/dashboard'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'medical/dashboard'
at ApplyRedirects.module.exports.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:74850:16)
at CatchSubscriber.selector (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:74825:29)
at CatchSubscriber.module.exports.CatchSubscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:91048:31)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at LastSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'medical/dashboard'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'medical/dashboard'
at ApplyRedirects.module.exports.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:74850:16)
at CatchSubscriber.selector (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:74825:29)
at CatchSubscriber.module.exports.CatchSubscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:91048:31)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
at LastSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
at resolvePromise (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86165:31)
at resolvePromise (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86136:17)
at D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86213:17
at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85819:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14821:37)
at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85818:36)
at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85586:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85979:35)
at ZoneTask.invoke (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85885:25)
at data.args.(anonymous function) (D:\dev\TSOUI\TSOUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:86691:25)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Hello, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @VyacheslavBorisov - I did not, I decided to put it on the back burner for the meantime.